# XmlSerializer - same element with different attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have xml containing:

```
<day p="d">
<day p="n">
```

What attributes do I need to add to Day class in order to deserialize the xml with XmlSerializer?

Comment: You need to give us a bit more to work with. Do you already have a c# class you're deserialising to? How about posting sample code and more XML?

Answer (score 1):

The following decorations -

```
[XmlType(TypeName="day")]
public class Day
{
    [XmlAttribute("p")]
    public string P { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("someObject")]
public class SomeObject
{
    [XmlArray("days")]
    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }
}
```

Would serialise to:

```
<someObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <days>
    <day p="n" />
    <day p="p" />
  </days>
</someObject>
```

Hope that gets you somewhere.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlElement("day")]
public class Day
{
  [XmlAttribute("p")]
  public string P {get;set;}
}
```